# Создание универсалных типов данных (структур) в Rust

Tags: rust

Изучаю Rust, хочу создать свою универсальную структуру и статический метод-шаблон для нее.
Возникает ошибка: "can't infer type for T"
В общем не может вывести тип для Т.
Хотя типы я явно указал в возвращаемом значении.
При объявлении переменной указание типа Cat тоже не помогает.

```rust
pub struct Cat<T, E> {
name: T,
age: E
}

impl<T, E> Cat<T, E> {

pub fn new() -> Cat<String, f32> {
 Cat {name: "Felix".to_string(), age: 0.01}

}}

fn main() {
  let cat = Cat::new();

}
```

Comment: Сделайте `impl Cat<String, f32>`

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо.